# DHCP Server stopped working

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, dhcp-server

I've been searching all day long, but nothing helped so far.

Computers without lease can't connect to the network. Everybody else who has an active lease doesn't have any problem.

We use DHCP Server from Windows Server 2012 R2, and I can see there is multiple 1342 and 1376 events, saying that ***scope is out of IP addresses*** and ***scope is 100 percent full with only 0 IP addresses available*** respectively.
[dhcp server events](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BSdiC.png)

But, if I see the scope statistics, says there is 56 addresses (21%) available
[scope statistics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lS6Xx.png)

I don't know what's happening, since in the last week we dropped from 80 to 30-40 devices connected to the network, and we have 255 addresses available in the current scope.

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

Delete all of the existing dynamic leases (not reservations). Devices that have a valid address will keep it and renew it at the next renewal interval. Devices that don't have a valid address should then be able to get one.

Answer (score 0):

I tried what @joeqwert suggested without success.

After try different methods, I deleted the scope and recreated it, and that solved the issue.